# How to avoid scientific notation in circe JSON serialization

Tags: json, scala, bigdecimal, circe

Let's say I have the next case class:

```
case class Person(id: String, money: BigDecimal)

object Person {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Person] = Encoder.forProduct2("ID", "Money")(u =>
    (u.id, u.money))
```

I want to serialize instances of the Person class to JSON, so when I evaluate the `asJson` from circe, I get the result in scientific notation:

```
{
    "ID" : "123",
    "VALOR_SAP" : 2.7E+7
}
```

Why do this happens? I think the reason is because the default to string of `BigDecimal` automatically format to scientific notation.

What could I do to avoid this? May be creating another type which extends from `BigDecimal` and overriding the `toString`?

Comment: The method `toPlainString()` avoids scientific notation. I guess you will have to find a way to use that, instead of the standard `toString()`.

Comment: That's right, however there is no way to extends the printer who execute that method. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. I don't have a definitive answer, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you use `scala.math.BigDecimal`, for `java.math.BigDecimal` code is similar. The way to change how objects are serialized is to provide corresponding implicit `Encoder` object. Unfortunately both `Json` and `JsonNumber` hierachies are sealed, so there is no very clean solution but you still can use `JsonNumber.fromDecimalStringUnsafe` that implements `toString` to just return any string you passed in. So you can do something like this:

```
case class Person(id: String, money: BigDecimal)

object Person {
  implicit final val bigDecimalAsPlainStringEncoder: Encoder[BigDecimal] = new Encoder[BigDecimal] {
    final def apply(value: BigDecimal): Json = Json.fromJsonNumber(JsonNumber.fromDecimalStringUnsafe(value.bigDecimal.toPlainString))
  }

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Person] = Encoder.forProduct2("ID", "Money")(u => (u.id, u.money))

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this seems the most suitable approach!